# SSIS Relative File Path for referencing .dtsx files on a execute package task

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, filepath, relative-path

Hi I have an SSIS package in which i have a main package that references child packages, is there a way I can make the location path external using a Relative path or just the file name. I cant use the full C: drive path as this is subject to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i found it is best to use the project reference system instead of file reference and you can reference any project file if you deploy to the SSISDB instead of the MSDB, it works much better than the MSDB as well as being able to work with package params easier

Answer (score 1):

yes, but you have to find a way of changing the current working directory of the execution of the package. I worked at one place where we ran bat files to execute the packages and the first line used cd to set the working directory to the folder location of the parent package. I think I've also seen people use a script task inside the parent package to set the working directory based on the runtime location of the parent package.

http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2008/7/13/relative-paths-in-ssis